# Why doesn't returning by ref work for elements of collections?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-7.0

The following example of returning by reference is from [What’s New in C# 7.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/):

```csharp
public ref int Find(int number, int[] numbers)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] == number)
        {
            return ref numbers[i]; // return the storage location, not the value
        }
    }
    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException($"{nameof(number)} not found");
}
```

That compiles without any problems (as you'd expect as it's copied from the Microsoft blog).

I've written this one:

```
private static ref int GetReference(string searchTerm)
{
    var passwords = new Dictionary<string, int>
    {
        {"password", 1},
        {"123456", 2},
        {"12345678", 3},
        {"1234", 4},
        {"qwerty", 5},
        {"12345", 6},
        {"dragon", 7}
    };

    return ref passwords[searchTerm];
}
```

This one doesn't compile though; it gives the following error:

> CS8156  An expression cannot be used in this context because it may not be returned by reference

Why does returning from an array work, but returning from a collection doesn't?

Comment: Since you declare `password` inside the method it goes out of scope when returning from `GetReference`. GC will (eventually) remove all references to it and you will not be able to access the correct data.

Comment: It would work if `passwords` was passed to the method through the arguments list, as in your first example.

Comment: My first attempt was having it as a field, that didn't work either.  It seems that it has to actually be passed in, rather than just in scope.

Comment: An array is different than a dictionary though. Even pre-ref returns in C# 6, you can pass an array slot as a ref into a method, but an indexer (like in a dictionary or list) cannot be.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is in that same link you posted:

> You can only return refs that are “safe to return”: Ones that were
>   passed to you, and ones that point into fields in objects.

Your example satisfies neither. You are creating the list inside the function (so the object will go out of scope and its pointer will be invalid), and it doesn't point to a field of an object.

Comment: It's not just fields. It's also array slots that can be passed as refs.

Comment: There is more to it: `Dictionary<,>`'s index property is not a valid expression for `ref`.  You can't provide `ref passwords[searchTerm]` as a ref argument.  So, the compiler will not evaluate if the ref is safe to return or not, because it's not a valid ref at all.

Comment: @acelent Yes I agree. This answer is misleading. It has nothing to do with `passwords` being a local. It's because the ref expression is invoking an indexer.

Answer (score 21):

In C#, `ref` works for:

- Variables (local or parameters)
- Fields
- Array locations

`ref` doesn't work for:

- Properties
- Events
- Local variables in the case of C# 7 return by ref

Note that for fields and array locations, it doesn't matter how you're accessing the array.  That is, `return ref numbers[i];` doesn't hold on to `numbers`, but to the array it points to.  Quite unlike `return ref numbers;`, which could only work if `numbers` was a field.

However, you're using `ref` on a `Dictionary<,>`'s index property, it's simply not a supported expression for `ref` to begin with (i.e. you can't pass `ref passwords[searchTerm]` as an argument even before C# 7), much less to return by ref.