# Is there a way to force a reference to another ref type in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, pointers

Here is my code:

```cs
public ref TComponent Get<TComponent>()
    where TComponent : struct, IComponent
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Components.Length; i++)
    {
        if (Components[i] is TComponent)
        {
            // CS8151: The return expression must be of type 'T' because this method returns by reference
            return ref Components[i];
        }
    }

    // throw an exception
}
```

So, as you can see, I am trying to return a reference to a specific object contained in an `IComponent[]` and I know that all these objects are value types.

The code would compile if my method returned a `ref IComponent` instead, but the problem would be the same as I would be forced to make the conversion at the output of the method.

I know that the object that I want to return has the right type and can be interpreted as a `TComponent` but the compiler can't know that and send me an error. First, I wanted to use pointers but they can be used on managed types.

So, here is my question: how can I tell the compiler that my object has the right type and can be returned by reference?

In other words, how can I convert a reference type to another ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't returning by ref work for elements of collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43576471/why-doesnt-returning-by-ref-work-for-elements-of-collections)

Comment: It seems like you need to cast your object, which means you should use classes instead of structs.

Comment: return ref (TComponent)Components[i];  ? OR         return ref (TComponent)(object)Components[i]; ?

Answer (score 0):

Generics are not meant to be used to return any type. Generics are type-safe. So whatever type you pass with the Get() method you need to return exactly that type.

Bat you could make all types inherit from the same interface or the same base type and then return that type.

Also, the comment of @RamblinRose needs to be taken in account

Comment: I am already doing this. TComponent inherits from IComponent. I edited the question as I forget to add this information.

Also, the question featured by @RamblinRose does not responds to mine.

Comment: Then the function signature would be _public ref IComponent Get()_ and you return _(IComponent)Components[i]_ . Oh and I would prefer it to be a class instead of a struct. That would make things simpler and more secure. You would not have to bother with the ref keyword, for instance