# Return reference of generic

Tags: c#, .net, generics, ref

How can I achieve something like this?

```
public class BlaBlaBla
{
    private PotatoesContainer _containerField;
    private bool _booleanField;

    private ref T GetBackingFieldRef<T>(string propertyName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(propertyName));

        if (propertyName == "BooleanProperty")
            return ref _booleanField;
        else if (propertyName == "ContainerProperty")
            return ref _containerField;

        throw new ArgumentException("Property does not exist", nameof(propertyName));
    }

    public void ManageProperty<T>(string propertyName, T newValue)
    {

        //Check stuff;

        var referenceToField = GetBackingFieldRef<T>(propertyName);

        referenceToField = newValue;

    }
}
```

I searched in all ref documentation and I cannot see anything. And I cannot cast calling `(T)`.

Is this possible?

Is there some other way (with `Action`, `Func` or something)?

Comment: Just for the code provided, try `return ref (T)(object)_booleanField;` : does it work?

Comment: @OlivierRogier Nope, I tried.

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to force a reference to another ref type in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59921406/is-there-a-way-to-force-a-reference-to-another-ref-type-in-c)

Comment: @OlivierRogier I edited, adding some code.

Comment: The whole point of a generic method is to have a method where the caller can provide any type they want and the method will behave properly, not write a method where the caller needs to provide exactly the right type and it breaks if they do anything else.  This method just shouldn't be generic in the first place.

Comment: @Servy I tried using `object` instead of generics but doesn't work because the valuetypes. How can I do it then?

Comment: @DrkDeveloper As the linked question tells you, you don't.  You can't use `ref` for something like this.

Comment: In addition to what Servy wrote, returning the backing field of a property in a public method seems like a pretty bad idea. The entire point of having properties is to restrict access to the backing field. In fact, even inside your own class you should probably think twice before accessing the backing field of a property directly from any part of your class that isn't the property code itself.

Comment: @Servy That is exactly what I was afraid of.

Comment: @ZoharPeled The method is private, that was a typo. But I understand what you say.

Comment: You could use reflection, return a FieldInfo from your GetBackingFieldRef and use  [FieldInfo.SetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.setvalue?view=net-5.0). But for what should be this good for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doable (as are most things), if you resort to using unsafe code. I would agree with the commenters that this is a **bad idea** and there are plenty of better ways to achieve what you're trying to do. However for educational purposes, here goes anyway:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

...

public unsafe ref T GetBackingFieldRef<T>(string propertyName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(propertyName));

    switch (propertyName)
    {
        case "BooleanProperty" when typeof(T) == typeof(bool):
            return ref Unsafe.AsRef<T>(Unsafe.AsPointer(ref _booleanField));
        case "ContainerProperty" when typeof(T) == typeof(PotatoesContainer):
            return ref Unsafe.AsRef<T>(Unsafe.AsPointer(ref _containerField));
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Property does not exist or type mismatch", nameof(propertyName));
    }
}
```

This uses `Unsafe.AsPointer<T>()` and `Unsafe.AsRef<T>()` to allow the otherwise difficult conversion to `ref T`. There's some checking of types to ensure that the type of `T` matches the type of the backing field, but this is of course very fragile - if you change the type of a backing field you'll have to remember to change the type checks, and will have to manually find all the calls to `GetBackingFieldRef<T>()` for that field and update them otherwise you'll get exceptions and/or memory corruption at runtime.

Comment: "and there are plenty of better ways", like which ones? I'm so uninspired

Comment: @DrkDeveloper You could just implement your `ManageProperty<T>()` via reflection as mentioned in one of the comments on your question, but ultimately this is a different question to the one you originally asked here. I'd suggest giving it a try and post a new question if you run into difficulties.